# knockout dynatree

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, dynatree

I need to be able to detect TreeView node drag and drop changes using Knockout and jquery.
This one is a good example but it only initializes the tree.
http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/EZgNs/
Thanks.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dynatree = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        setTimeout( function() { $(element).dynatree()}, 0);
    }
};
```

Ashraf

Comment: what do you mean by drag and drop changes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, but DnD support is provided in the dynatree control.  You just need to add the `dnd` init parameter - the documentation is [here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h6).  I've updated the fiddle to [demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/EZgNs/182/).

Comment: John, Thanks for your effort. what you did is very close to what I need. I'm new to knockout. 
I just need to verify that moving a node is reflected on the ViewModel. I will do some testing as soon as I can and post the result. Thanks again.

Comment: Ashraf, unfortunately the ViewModel will not be effected. Dynatree creates new DOM elements from those that Knockout generated. Normally you could use the `ko.contextFor(node)` and `ko.dataFor(node)` functions to retrieve the ViewModel elements that we could use to mirror the move, but they return `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you very much John. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.
No problem. I guess I will have to do it the old way then, through serialization.

Comment: Not how you're doing your serialization, but if you want to abstract it into the binding, you can do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/tJHLL/).  it doesn't update the data the way you need (I just used toDict()), and should be more robust, but you can see the general idea.

Comment: Thanks heiserman your solution is a good workaround for the problem.